# Open in same browser tab from Trello

Tags: html, trello

I am creating a link in a Trello card to an external link. What I want to achieve is that this link opens in the same browser tab ( _self ) or opens in a new browser tab and return to this tab if the link is activated again. As it is now it generates a new browser tab every time clicking the link. Is there any suggestion to achieve this ?

Comment: You want to achieve - open in the same browser tab.
As it is now it generates a new browser tab every time clicking the link.
Could you please check your question again?

Comment: Exactly, this is what i want to achieve. Just like  <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_self">Visit W3Schools</a>

Comment: Okay reformulating the question : As far as I see it I am restricted by Trello's markdown syntax. I am creating a link in a Trello card and activating this link always create a new  browser tab. I want to stay in the tab or return to the same tab activating the link. Just like defined by a target="_self" or target="name"

Answer (score 0):

You can set specific window's name, in order to open reuse the tab. You can do the following way.

```
<a href="foo" onclick="window.open(this.href, this.href); return false">Foo</a>
<a href="bar" onclick="window.open(this.href, this.href); return false">Bar</a>
```

Or this way also..

```
<div id="tabopen">
    <a href="bar">link</a>
</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById("tabopen").onclick = function(evt){
        if (evt.target.tagName === "A")
            window.open(evt.target.href, evt.target.href);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: As far as I see it I am restricted by Trello's markdown syntax. I am creating a link in a Trello card and activating this link always create a new  browser tab. I want to stay in the tab or return to the same tab activating the link.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but I thought I should add that in 2022:

- Adding a link as an **attachment** to the card opens the url in a **new** tab when you click on it.
- Adding a link as text in the **description** of the card opens the link in **the same** tab when you click on it.